# Prove $\lim _{ n\to\infty } \sqrt [ n ]{ \sum _{ i=0 }^{ k } a_i ^n } =\max { \{{ a }_{ 1 }, \ldots ,{ a }_{ k }\} } $

Tags: calculus, limits

We know that
$$ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k \ge 0 $$

Prove that:
$$\lim _{ n\to\infty } \sqrt [ n ]{ \sum _{ i=0 }^{ k } a_i ^n }  =\max { \{{ a }_{ 1 }, \ldots ,{ a }_{ k }\} } $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide by the Maximum of them and show the limit is 1, by using $$\max a_i\leq  \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \leq k \cdot \max a_i $$(if all $a_i=0$ the limit is trivial).

Wlog $a_1\geq a_i \forall i$. Then
\begin{align*}
a_1=\sqrt[n]{a_1^n}\leq \Big(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^n\Big)^\frac{1}{n}&=a_1 \cdot \Big( \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{a_i}{a_1}\right)^n\Big)^\frac{1}{n}\leq a_1 \cdot \sqrt[n]{k}
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you please show your way in a more details? thanks

Comment: @DanBarzilay $\max a_i^n\leq \sum a_i^n\leq k\max a_i^n\Rightarrow \max a_i\leq \left(\sum a_i^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq k^{\frac{1}{n}}\max a_i\to \max a_i$ as $n\to\infty$