# limit of a finite sequence (if I read it correctly)

Tags: calculus, limits

this is the limit to evaluate:

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \root n \of {{a_1}^n + {a_2}^n + ...{a_k}^n}  = \max \{ {a_1}...{a_k}\}   \cr 
  & {a_1}...{a_k} \ge 0 \cr} $$

As far as I understand, $a_1..a_k$ is finite. right?
Suppose it is, I'm clueless about the solution. Hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Often with these type of analysis questions a common technique is to show that LHS$\geq$ RHS and LHS$\leq$RHS.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446760/prove-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-sum-i-0-k-a-i-n-max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to see this equality. First notice that for all $i$ and for all $n$,
$$a_i\leq \sqrt[n]{a_1^n+ \ldots + a_k^n}$$
hence we have
$$\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\} \leq \sqrt[n]{a_1^n+ \ldots + a_k^n}$$
for all $n$, hence
$$\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1^n+ \ldots + a_k^n}$$
To show the other inequality, suppose that $a_i$ is the maximum of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$. Then
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1^n+ \ldots + a_k^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{ka_i^n}$$
Then we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1^n+ \ldots + a_k^n}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{k} a_i = a_i = \max\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $k$ is a finite number then {$a_1,a_2,..,a_k$} is a finite subset of $\Bbb R$ and thus has a maximum element. Let's say that $\max \{ {a_1}...{a_k}\}=a_i$ and $b$ is the times that $a_i=a_j$ for $j=1,2,...,n$ then $\root n \of {{a_1}^n + {a_2}^n + ...{a_k}^n}=\root n \of {a_i^n(b+({\frac {a_1}{a_i}})^n + ({\frac {a_2}{a_i}})^n + ...({\frac {a_k}{a_i}})^n})=a_i\root n \of {b+({\frac {a_1}{a_i}})^n + ({\frac {a_2}{a_i}})^n + ...({\frac {a_k}{a_i}})^n}$ where $({\frac {a_1}{a_i}})^n,({\frac {a_2}{a_i}})^n,...,({\frac {a_n}{a_i}})^n\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$ because $\frac {a_1}{a_i},\frac {a_2}{a_i},...,\frac {a_n}{a_i}< 1$. So we have $a_i\sqrt[n] b\to a_i\cdot 1=a_i$.